# what is the equivalent of GIT_SSL_CAINFO for svn?

Tags: git, svn, certificate

with git you can specify the certificate to use

```
GIT_SSL_CAINFO=/etc/ca-bundle.crt
```

what would be the equivalent command for subversion ?

So far I have only seen extra command to add to `svn` but I was hoping to run a external script leaving it untouched.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

svn was relying on outside SSL_CERT_FILE from OpenSSH in my system (NixOS)